# Select option - replace & with regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I am making an option select function that takes the add a unique dynamic url and replaces the

```
&amp;
```

with

```
&
```

in the URL.

Jquery

```
$("#pageSizeOptions").change(function () {
   document.location.href = ('?ViewAction=View&amp;ObjectID=1710211').replace(/(\?|&amp;)(PageSize=[^&amp;]+)(&amp;|$)/, '$3') + $(this).val();
});
```

Perl Template (jquery)

```
$("#pageSizeOptions").change(function () {
   document.location.href = ('#Pager.URL').replace(/(\?|&amp;)(PageSize=[^&amp;]+)(&amp;|$)/, '$3') + $(this).val();
});
```

OUTCOME:

```
http://fiddle.jshell.net/RFfXs/5/show/light/?ViewAction=View&amp;ObjectID=1710211&PageSize=40
```

EXPECTED OUTCOME:

```
http://fiddle.jshell.net/RFfXs/5/show/light/?ViewAction=View&ObjectID=1710211&PageSize=40
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RFfXs/5/

Can anyone help on what exactly i am doing wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cP5Qs/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("#pageSizeOptions").change(function () {
   console.log(('?ViewAction=View&amp;ObjectID=1710211').replace('&amp;', '&') + $(this).val());
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RFfXs/7/)